# How come they couldn't heal Captain Pike's injuries in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness, star-trek-2009

As we saw in the Star Trek movies and TV shows, the Federation has extraordinarily advanced knowledge, science, medicine and technology. They were able to cure all fatal injuries, horrible diseases etc. quickly.

**So, how come they couldn't cure Captain Pike's injuries in Star Trek (2009)?**

They did offer a wheelchair in *Star Trek* and a cane in *Star Trek into Darkness*.

Comment: And in the TV show, Pike was able to kept alive after going through lots of trauma. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Pike_(Star_Trek)): "the delta ray radiation leaving him paralyzed, mute, badly scarred, and dependent on a brainwave-operated wheelchair."

Comment: Explain "Red Shirts", then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can't cure injuries. You treat them. But the Federation medical science, while advanced, is still incapable of treating severe damage immediately. Even in the TNG era, severe spinal injuries can leave someone in a wheelchair. Only experimental spinal transporter surgery helped Worf. The reboot movies are set hundreds of years before TNG. They still don't have instant bone repair like TNG.